# How to access system.xml values in phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

```
$extensionStatus=$this->helper('Esparksinc\Extension\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Extension/general/enableDisable');
```

i am accesing this way but it gaves me a warning "The use of helpers in templates is discouraged. Use ViewModel
     instead" while checking code in magento coding standared.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `$this->helper(...)` in template file.

To get helper in template, you should add the helper instance to block dependency and create method in the block class to get the helper instance.

Example:

```
namespace Esparksinc\Extension\Block;

use Esparksinc\Extension\Helper\Data as Helper;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class YourBlock extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Helper
     */
    private $helper;

    /**
     * @param Helper           $helper
     * @Param Template/Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Helper $helper,
        Template\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return Helper
     */
    public function getHelper()
    {
        return $this->helper;
    }
}
```

To get the helper in template file:

```
// get helper instance
$helper = $block->getHelper();

// call public method inside helper
$extensionStatus = $helper->getConfig('Extension/general/enableDisable');
```

Comment: where is the ->getConfig  defined?

Comment: I have updated the answer, it should be `$helper->getConfig('Extension/general/enableDisable');`

Comment: Thanks Alot .its working perfect .but what is in the case when we use view model for this.

Comment: I found this article interesting to answer your question: https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-12-viewmodels-in-magento-2 (in `When to use ViewModels?` part)